# UseUnityServiceProvider doesn't works properly on WebApplicationBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, unity-container

I'm trying to migrate from `.NET3.1` to `.NET6.0` WebAPI. I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#apps-migrating-to-or-using-60-and-later-dont-need-to-use-the-new-minimal-hosting-model) as manual to do this migration.

I'm using `UnityContainer` as `DependencyInjection` framework. So in `.NET3.1` I have something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUnityServiceProvider() // Here is UnityServiceProvider registeration.
        .UseNLog()
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();

            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        });
}
```

This `IHostBuilder` using `UseUnityServiceProvider` with a `Startup.cs` calls a method named `ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)` in my `Startup.cs` which is responsible to register all `Dependencies`.

After moving to `.NET6.0` I replaced `Program.cs` with this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.WebHost.UseUnityServiceProvider(); // Using .WebHost I'm able to add UnityServiceProvider

        builder.WebHost.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        });

        var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);

        startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

        var app = builder.Build();

        startup.Configure(app, app.Environment);

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't causes to any call to my `ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)`. So I have nothing registered on UnityContainer. and my whole `DI` is useless.

Any advice on this ?

Comment: Why not call the `ConfigureContainer` on manually created container and then use the overload `UseUnityServiceProvider(container)`? Let me know if this resolves your issue (it's a possible answer).

Comment: Do we have any resolution from Unity on this? I prefer builder.WebHost.UseUnityServiceProvider(); does the job and I do not have to inject all the dependencies that are already loaded by Unity.

Comment: as @sorosh_sabz answered below unity seems out of support. so I have decided to migrate to another third-party (sh*t-party) called AutoFac 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [unity official site](http://unitycontainer.org/), Unity says

> If your project depends on Unity container and you want it to be
> maintained and developed, please support it. Remember, I can have only
> one full time job, so without proper financial backing there will be
> no more releases beyond v5.11

and if you see [Unity GitHub](https://github.com/unitycontainer) you can see reduce activity in development is significant.

So unfortunately I think unity in semi-deprecation state.

I suggest to you, use [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) instead of unity for modern .NET. and if you want use Autofac in configuration based on .NET 6 you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76836609/1539100) as sample and below code

```cs
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("autofac.json");
            var autoFacConfigurationModule = new ConfigurationModule(configurationBuilder.Build());
            var temp = new IpTablesDotNetSystem();

            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory((containerBuilder) =>
            {
                containerBuilder.RegisterModule(autoFacConfigurationModule);
                //containerBuilder.RegisterType<IpTablesDotNetSystem>().As<IIpTablesSystem>().SingleInstance();
            }
            ));
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
```